# Unity 5.4 Button auto-clicks

Tags: c#, scripting, unityscript, unity-game-engine

When I create a button in unity3d 5.4 the button just clicks automatic when i press play in the editor. I haven't been using unity before, so I can't say if it would happen in other versions.

First i create a script, then I attatch it to a empty gameobject. Then I press the little + sign on the OnClick() in the button properties, so I can add the gameobject with the script attached.

I have screenshots of button properties, eventSystem, Canvas, gameobject and the Script.

If anyone know what i have done wrong, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

The screenshots are in this post, since I cant post 5 images in stackoverflow:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-4-button-auto-clicks.426526/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press play in editor, Button is **NOT** pressed at all. Its just that you have `Debug.Log("Clicked!")` in `Start()` method. `Start()` is called by Unity automatically when you run the application. It has nothing to do with button click. You need to register `OnClick()` listener method so it will be called when you press the button.

Have a look at this tutorial : https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button

**EDIT :**

Please learn more about scripting here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting

Comment: This is unbelievable.  I think that OP needs to [understand](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting) what the Start() and Update() functions are before going forward.

Comment: YES! it was a quicker from my side tho added the *understand* part